# Two or more Diac Triac dimmers in parallel

Tags: ac, triac, dimmer, lamp, diac

I wanted to know whether connecting two or more simple diac-triac ac lamp dimmers in parallel with the same load cause any problems?
I do not want to connect them in series, just parallel will be enough.

The dimmer circuit is the common diac-triac dimmers found in stores and wired in paralled like this .
[image]

The load will be a dimmable led light bulb at 240v ac 12w.

Edit: Updated circuit diagram

Comment: This sounds indeed like a bad idea. *Why* would you want to put the triac dimmers in parallel, and *how exactly* do you plan to put them in parallel? Draw a schematic of at least *2* parallel dimmers so that we see which components you want to only have one time, and which components you want to have multiple times.

Comment: I've updated the schematic to make it easier to illustrate.

Comment: ah, much better, thanks! Still confused what you need this for!

Comment: I'll explain. I will set 3 different dimmers at different dim settings. Then I will connect each of the dimmers through their own individual relays. So that If I want a certain brightness I can switch that relay on and the saved dim setting will light the lamp. I wanted to know if by accident I turn on 2 or more relays at once will there be any problems.

Comment: ah, ok, but why don't you just use three different resistors / potentiometers and just switch between these?

Comment: @MarcusMüller you mean replace the VR1 with a resistor?

Comment: Marcus is right. You could have three pots switchable by your relays. This means that your relays aren't switching lamp current - just a few mA and so they can be smaller and last longer.

Comment: @Transistor Ok, but are those pots acting as rheostats? if yes then can't I use resistors instead?

Comment: Sure, but pots give you some flexibility to adjust later without getting the soldering iron out.

Comment: @Transistor I want fixed values which is why I had 3 different dimmers in the first place. Are the pots in this circuit acting as voltage dividers or as variable resistor/rheostat?

Comment: The wipers of the pots are directly connected to one end of the pot, so the pot is acting as a simple variable resistor/rheostat.

Comment: @PeterBennett  Thanks for the info, So can I use 1/4 watt resistor as substitute or should I go with more wattage rating?

Comment: @Kokachi don't know, depends on the diac and triac, but simply go with the same rating as your current pot?

Comment: @MarcusMüller ok, but I can't find the datasheet, it's a chinese one named WH149 500k. 1/2 watt is the maximum I can find here for ordinary resitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parallel connection of 2-wire dimmer switches is fine.

Note that the first one to switch on will control the brightness. i.e., The one with the brightest setting will win. This is due to the way the triacs in the dimmers switch on at a certain point in the mains cycle.

[image]

*Figure 1. Triac dimmer control. Note that the earlier in the mains cycle that the power is switched on the brighter the lamps.*

> I do not have a problem if the brightest one wins. I just want to know whether they will create a short or explode or destroy the load.

No, there will not be a short. The first one to switch on will drop the voltage across the other dimmers close to zero and the C1 on each of those will not charge any further and those triacs will not turn on.

---

The question changed somewhat after I wrote the answer in that OP can accept a "one triac" solution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuefMH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. A relay controlled dimmer with three preset power levels.*

Figure 2 shows how to wire the dimmer for three-point relay control. The 4k7 resistor can be omitted provided the other resistors are greater than 4k7. I have laid the circuit out with the triac on the live wire as would normally be the case in a fixed installation. It will work either way.

Comment: by 2-wire dimmers you mean the dimmers which are connected to load only through the live wire? I've updated the circuit diagram to illustrate it better.

Comment: I do not have a problem if the brightest one wins. I just want to know whether they will create a short or explode or destroy the load.

Comment: While the parallel connection with work with three complete dimmers, you can significantly cost reduce the solution by having only one Triac. Then you'd have just the three R/C/Diac networks with the common for the Diacs connected to a single Triac.  Whichever Diac fires first turns on the output Triac.

Comment: @JackCreasey If possible can you show me a diagram. Cost is not a problem as these dimmers cost only half a dollar each including shipping.

Comment: @Kokachi: See the update. "*... these dimmers cost only half a dollar each including shipping.*" Now I'm worried.

Comment: @Transistor  Perfectly clear schematic, just worried about the power rating for individual resistors. 1/2 watt is the maximum I can find. 1 watt above cement resistors available here only go upto 20 ohms.

Comment: The potentiometer you are replacing was probably only rated at 1/8 W. 1/4 W should be fine. You can measure the voltage drop across them with a true RMS meter to check - although the "crest factor" will be high and may introduce some error into your reading depending on the quality of your meter. Use \$ P = \frac {V^2}{R} \$ to calculate the power.

Comment: @Transistor  the single resistor before the pot is 1/4W anyway. I don't have a true rms meter, just a generic heap meter.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to tackle the problem of providing 3 pre-set light levels.

1. Three R/C/Diac networks and one Triac

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdUApX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or even simpler still....

2. Just three potentiometers, one DIAC and one Triac

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2funCXH.png)</sup>

You could fairly easily modify a single dimmer to satisfy either of the schemes above.

**Note:** The schematic you show is not the most reliable (the trigger point), and typically two R/C networks are used to provide much better reliability.
You should also include a snubber to prevent radiated noise.

[image]

Comment: I would go with solution no.2. I have a question,can the resistors used to replace the pot be of 1/4W? The single resistor before the pot is of 1/4W power rating anyway.

Comment: It depends on the potentiometer value for any given phase angle. You might see peak dissipation up to about 1/3 W, so to be overconfident, I'd suggest you use 1/2 W resistors.

Comment: Ok, 1/2W resistors are available, I can go with that.  You mentioned that my schematic was not that reliable, is it really a concern?

Comment: Reliable trigger point, rather than reliability (failure) of the dimmer device. I'd recommend the snubber be added, but you may not notice any effects from the trigger point movement.

Comment: you mean the each time the circuit turns on the dimming level might be erratic or unpredictable?

Comment: Yes. However with LED lights there is typically a CC source or some capacitance which should smooth this out. When using incandescent lights you can see brightness variations caused by slight changes in the AC voltage level.

Comment: I thought that the triac will trigger at random brightness outputs each time I turn on. My concern is that if I set the resistance at a certain brightness level which I like, I want to get that same level every time I turn the lamp on. Will this be affected?

Comment: No. The dimmer works as you wish for any preset potentiometer value ...providing the AC voltage and frequency remains the same. So you can expect to get the same brightness each time you turn the dimmer on (within certain limits). The RC time constant is, well ...constant, but the time taken to trigger the Diac will vary slightly with changes in both voltage and frequency. Will you notice? ...doubtful....but you might get some change or flicker when the Fridge turns on, or you turn on a vacuum cleaner for example.

Comment: now I get it, you mean there will be brightness variations when there is variation in mains voltage and frequency. like the way an ordinary lamp dims when I turn on the air conditioner. This can be avoided with your circuit?

Comment: No the circuit I supplied won't eliminate the problem, but the two RC network does improve resistance to noise (which is part of the problem).